# NGINX redirect accesses by IP to access by domain name dont work

Tags: nginx, 301-redirect, settings

Every time instead domain browser in address line display ip address of server.

Please let me know how can I redirect it to my domain?
I have following setting, but dont work.

```
upstream app {
     server unix:/home/deploy/sharetribe/tmp/sockets/puma.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;



        root /home/deploy/sharetribe/public;

        try_files $uri/index.html $uri @app;

        location @app {
                proxy_pass http://app;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_redirect off;

        }

server_name domain.name  www.domain.name;

        location / {
            # root /home/deploy/sharetribe/public;
             try_files $uri @app;
             gzip_static on;
             expires max;
             proxy_read_timeout 150;
             add_header Cache-Control public;
        }
}

server {
   listen 80;
   server_name 12.123.12.12;
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
   #rewrite .* http://domian.name$request_uri permanent;  
   return 301 $scheme://domain.name$request_uri;
}
```

**UPDATE:**

```
root@a:~# curl -I http://domain.name/
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx/1.10.2
Date: Sat, 11 Mar 2017 19:42:06 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 185
Connection: keep-alive
Location: http://domain.name/
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
```

Display error in google chrome: **domain.name redirected you too many times.**

Comment: You have two `server` blocks listening on port 80 with the same `server_name`. Have you tried removing `12.123.12.12` from the top one?

Comment: 12.123.12.12 page isn’t working

12.123.12.12 redirected you too many times.

Comment: Please add details of the exact request made to the server and what is the exact response from the server when you get a response you are not looking for.

Comment: i updated unswer. how me see request made to the server and what is the exact response from the server?